# How to send multiple time response from one endpoint in Java springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Scenario:
I have 30 testcases for end-to-end process flow that includes (scheduler, producer and consumer). So, I'm automating the 30 testcase in java springmvc web application. I have created an endpoint which is to start testing, then it will run 30 testcase one after other in order, I have created 30 methods for each testcase, each test case approx takes 5 min to complete because (have to execute scheduler, producer and consumer). so, after one test case is complete, I want to show in UI the status and message, I don't want to wait till all the 30 testcase completion then show status of all testcase. How to achieve this using rest endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Summary

send multiple via same end point , it is not `REST API`  scenario. In general , we often use Long connection to handle this scenario , there many tech to choose  like websocket , tcp protocol , socket , but all of them are too heavy , just send a mejssage to specified host may  configure so much .

#### Solution

In a nutshell ,  there is  [Server-Sent Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) could easy solve your problem ,  i would demonstrae bacic demo for this tech  in spring ， also you can read [offical spring sse doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-ann-async.html#mvc-ann-async-sse)

##### 1. set up endpoint in spring

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter;

import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sse")
public class SseController {

    @GetMapping("/events")
    public SseEmitter handleSse() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();

        // Asynchronous processing to send events
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    // Send events every 1 second
                    emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().name("message").data("Event " + i));

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                // Signal the end of the event stream
                emitter.complete();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                emitter.completeWithError(e);
            }
        }).start();

        return emitter;
    }
}
```

##### connect endpoint by client side

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SSE Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SSE Example</h1>
    <div id="sse-events"></div>

    <script>
        const eventSource = new EventSource('/sse/events');

        eventSource.onmessage = function (event) {
            const eventsDiv = document.getElementById('sse-events');
            eventsDiv.innerHTML += `<p>${event.data}</p>`;
        };

        eventSource.onerror = function (error) {
            console.error('EventSource failed:', error);
            eventSource.close();
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, the /sse/events endpoint in the SseController returns an SseEmitter, and a separate thread is used to send events asynchronously. The JavaScript code on the client side uses the EventSource API to listen for events and update the HTML content.

Remember to configure your Spring Boot application with appropriate dependencies, and you may need to handle exceptions and cleanup appropriately in a production scenario.

#### Appendix

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version> // replace appropriate  version , 3.0.0 or else later is ok
      </dependency>
```

you can find major class at following package path (may different from other spring boot version )

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve real-time updates of test case statuses in a Spring Boot application, you'll need to use an asynchronous communication method. Traditional REST endpoints are synchronous and request-response based, meaning the client makes a request and waits for a response, which isn't suitable for your requirement. Here are some approaches you can consider:

1. **WebSocket**: This is a good choice for real-time communication between the server and the client. Spring Boot supports WebSocket and it allows bi-directional communication. You can send a message to the client each time a test case completes.
2. **Server-Sent Events (SSE)**: SSEs are a simpler alternative to WebSockets. They allow the server to push data to the client. It's a one-way communication from the server to the client. Spring has support for SSE through the `SseEmitter` class.
3. **Long Polling**: This is another approach where the client makes a request to the server and the server holds the request open until it has new data to send back. It's less efficient than WebSockets or SSE but can be easier to implement in some cases.
4. **Messaging Queues**: Using a message broker like RabbitMQ or Apache Kafka, you can publish messages (test case statuses) to a queue/topic, and the client can subscribe to these messages. This might be more complex to set up but is very powerful and scalable.

Implementing any of these will require some changes on both the server side and the client side. Here's a general idea of how you can proceed:

- Modify your endpoint to start the test cases asynchronously. You can use `@Async` annotation in Spring Boot to easily run methods asynchronously.
- Choose a real-time communication method (WebSocket, SSE, etc.).
- Implement the server-side logic to send updates after each test case completes.
- Update your client-side application to handle these real-time updates.

Remember, the exact implementation will depend on the specific technologies and architecture of your application.